# Cant redirect inside lazy loaded module (angular)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

There is my app routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'public', loadChildren: 'app/public/public.module#PublicModule' },
  { path: 'crm', loadChildren: 'app/crm/crm.module#CrmModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/public', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }      
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

App module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And public routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [  
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'feed' },
  {
    path: 'feed', component: Public.PublicHostComponent, children: [
      { path: 'sign-up', component: Public.SignUpComponent, outlet: 'signUpPopup' },
      { path: '', component: Public.PublicMainComponent } 
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class PublicRoutingModule { }
```

And PublicHostComponent is just a wrapper that contains next

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="signUpPopup"></router-outlet>
```

The problem is next.
When I go to root `localhost:4200` it redirects me to `localhost:4200/public` and that's all, there is only blank page, but when I type `localhost:4200/public` it redirects me to right route (`localhost:4200/public/feed`).
What is the reason of such behavior ?

**Edit**

When I've removed slash from this line `('/public' => 'public')`

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/public', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

in app routing module, routing started to work as expected.